# NHibernate begin transaction and commit with no statements takes more then 4 seconds

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, nhprof

I run Nh-Prof on our production and found that the time to open NHibernate session, begin transaction and commit sometimes takes more than 4 seconds even there are no state/queries to database.

** I know that open transaction and commit it with no reason (no statements) is a bug.

This is what I see in Nh-Prof:

```
begin transaction with isolation level: Unspecified
commit transaction
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should only be building the session factory once. Building the session factory is quite expensive. How often are you doing that?

Comment: You need to profile each action to have a more detailed insight into what's the source of the problem. In your question, there are at least three actions: open connection, begin transaction, commit transaction. NHProfiler only gives you the SQL statements and their execution time, and transaction commands time are not available. Your application might be busy doing something else, who know?

Comment: is it 4 seconds between `begin` and `commit` ?? can you prove that to yourself with using a stopwatch between statements?

Comment: @Andrew I use the session factory only once

Comment: @RIPPO I am sure that his takes 4 seconds

Answer (score 1):

### Most probable reason:

the session used is "full" of objects and on Commit it checks each object if it has changed to generate an update statement. Even if nothing changed the check is costly.

You can check `session.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.EntitiesByKey.Count` to see how many objects are there.

### What you can do about it:

- don't use this session to load readonly data (e.g. fillling a readonly grid)
- use session.Evict along the way on objects you don't need anymore for the transaction and haven't changed